# Populating range from array

Tags: excel, vba, transpose

I have a worksheet change event that runs when three adjacent cells in columns C, D and E are filled with any value, which puts the date of entry into a separate worksheet as well as the name of the sheet where the data was captured from.

Then the code is supposed to count all instances of those dates for each day of the year.

If I step through the array FrstLetter is outputting the correct value.
Where I'm struggling: it then outputs said value back via `application.transpose(myarray)` as no value is input when it loops through.

```vb
With Sheets("Log")
    For RowCount = 1 To 60

        Select Case RowCount

        Case 2, 7, 12, 17, 22, 27, 32, 37, 42, 47, 52, 57
            LastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            DateRange = WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Range("F" & RowCount & ":AJ" & RowCount))
            For TypCount = 1 To 3
                SheetIdent = .Cells(RowCount + TypCount, 5).Value
                For ClmnNmbr = 1 To DateRange
                    ReDim AddrArr(DateRange)
                    AddrArr(ClmnNmbr) = .Cells(RowCount, ClmnNmbr + 5).Value

                    Set arrDates = .Range("A60:A" & LastRow)
                    Set shtNames = .Range("B60:B" & LastRow)
                    
                    ReDim FrstLetter(DateRange)
                    FrstLetter(ClmnNmbr) = Application.CountIfs(arrDates, AddrArr(ClmnNmbr), shtNames, SheetIdent)

                    Worksheets("Log").Cells(TypCount + RowCount, ClmnNmbr + 5).Value = Application.Transpose(FrstLetter)
                Next ClmnNmbr
            Next TypCount

        Case Else
        
        End Select
    Next RowCount
                        
End With
```

I have a feeling I'm messing up somewhere with the transpose because everything else seems to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, don't try to empty your entire array into one cell is the answer! `Application.Transpose(FrstLetter(ClmnNmbr))` adding `ClmnNmbr` made sure, as it was looping, only one value was output per cell since the cells were also being looped through.